# Why is 48" too deep for a workbench?

Tags: workbench

[One article on workbench design](https://www.popularwoodworking.com/woodworking-blogs/mistakes-first-time-bench-builders/) said the following was a basic mistake of first time builders:

> 6. Building the DIY workbench too deep
>
> There are many reasons that workbenches plans aren’t 48” deep. The
>   workbench is a lot less useful if it’s that deep. Here’s a hint, the
>   benchtop should be less deep than your casework to make it easier to
>   work on the casework.

They don't really explain this too well. What are the "many reasons" 48" is too deep?

I am building a workbench that is not just for woodworking but metalworking tasks like supporting tools such as a 3-ton arbor press. Also, I may be working with 4x8 sheet goods.

Comment: Looks like a good article.  Thanks for the link.   I don't know enough about bench design to offer an answer, but the article does seem to be "furniture building"-centric.  Like yourself, I use my workbench for many diversified activities.  His reference to casework is revealing however, suggesting that in his use of a work bench it is common to have the outer shell of a unfinished piece of furniture strattling the bench with side walls hanging down while the front or back rests on the bench's work surface.  This is the only scenario where I see bench width coming into play.

Comment: My old assembly table was approximately 4'x8' whith a laminated top (Formica) but had access to 3 of the 4 sides one short side spent its against a wall it did not survive the move

Answer (score 3):

How many things are you building that are more than 24" deep?  Too deep of a workbench prevents you from reaching the back of whatever you are working on.  I can only think of a few things I have built ever that were deeper than 24", and almost everything else would have been a pain to build on a wider bench.

You mention supporting tools such as your arbor press.  My experience has been that while it seems like a good idea at first to put those things on your bench, it doesn't work all that well.  The work surface should be as open as possible, to allow for the most versatile use of the space.  If you need to mount tools to it temporarily, look into a system that uses hitch receivers to 'plug in' different vices and presses on an as needed basis.

Finally, depending upon the types of projects you are doing, you may want to consider totally different benches for metal work vs wood work.  I wouldn't want to work on a nice piece of hardwood furniture on the same bench I used for repairing a chainsaw and welding.

Answer (score 1):

A workbench is a very personal tool that should be customized for the intended user and the intended use. A bench that might work perfect for one person could be very difficult for someone else, or not work well at all. You need to consider your environment, such as shop space and other obstacles to decide on size and height. Since you indicated a variety of projects, such as metal working and large sheet goods, and you can walk all the way around your planned bench, a 48" top may be appropriate.

You also want to think about what the top is made of, if metalworking will be done, it may need to be impervious to oils (maybe a laminate layer or even metal on some or all of it). Next, think about a vice (or vices) that you might want and how they would attach to the top. Will there be an overhang on some or all of it? I have a large top on my bench and it has a 4" - 6" overhang so that I can use clamps and bench dogs easily.

Don't forget about the base, I have found that a heavy, sturdy base makes the whole bench work better and more durable. I put some big metal wheels below mine so that I could move it around although admittedly it doesn't get moved very often. A well built frame will also allow you to put drawers and doors that won't rack when you put stress on the bench. Another issue when thinking about the base is the height of the bench. I made one of my benches 30" in height, primarily because it's easier to lift sheet goods to that height (rather than 36") and most of the activity (drawing dimensions, cutting with circular saw, cabinet assembly, etc.) on a slightly lower bench makes it easier.

So, as you can see, a bench is a personal tool that works for you regardless of whether it works for somebody else. You should take all of the comments, recommendations and magazine articles as advice (including my comments) and use it to design and build the bench that works best for you.

Lastly, when designing the bench, do it with the thought of using it 5 years from now and thinking to yourself, "I'm glad I built it this way".

Answer (score 0):

Most woodworking benches are designed to be against walls (partly for lighting) and 48" is a long way to reach across a bench. With less wide benches you can also support casework over the end of the bench. Space and cost are other considerations which favour smaller benches. Given situations where you would gain via adding width are rare for a bench designed for woodworking, length is typically prioritized so you can support longer stock. Additionally, other support solutions like bents can easily be used to add length or width without taking up too much space.

If your 48" bench isn't against a wall and you can use both sides it should work ok for both cases without much compromise.

Comment: In my case, it is a 360-degree walkaround, however there is a reach issue. The only situation where I see the reach issue being important is if I have something on the other side of the bench that has to be pulled down or across, like a radial arm saw or a hinged fence.